# Working out percentages for payment table

Tags: probability-distributions, percentages

I'm here because my mathematics skills are lacking somewhat for a problem i'm trying to solve..

I'm trying to work out a formula for prize distribution for the top 3rd of entrants in a competition.

All entrants pay a fixed amount to enter (£4.50)
(The number of entrants is not a fixed number, there's no maximum number of entrants)

totalPrizePool = entryFee * number of players

Prizes are to be paid out to the top 3rd of entrants.
totalWinners = totalEntrants / 3

totalPrizePool needs to be split between the totalWinners

Where the top placed winner is a higher percentage than the lowest placed winner. and dropping for the next place, until all winners have received a percentage.

Whats the easiest way to work out the percentage drops from 1st to last place?

I hope my question makes sense and is possible to calculate.

Any pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

I intend write some php code to do the calculations, just need to know what steps to take to do the calculations

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, there are quite many ways to go about doing this. Can you think of any more constraints? Or is it fine as long as winner $\#n$ gets a larger prize than winner $\#n+1$?

Comment: what do you mean by "(totalWinners = totalEntrants / 3 )"

Comment: @Vikram: I believe he means that if $3n$ people play, $n$ people will win something.

Comment: @Regret So long as each prize is more than the one before it, it would be better if it was weighted so the top prizes are weighted higher than the rest,

Comment: @Dizzy: One thing that pops to my mind: Do all winners need to be rewarded at least the entry fee?

Comment: @regret no thats not an issue really, I will be using this to work out the payouts for a fantasy football game, this will be used for very large contests up to 5000 players, its not important that the payout they receive covers their entry fee.

Comment: @Regret If it is possible to put in a minimum payout i would have it set to say 50p

Comment: One approach is to use Geometric Progression, $S=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$, here $S$ is the sum which can be set to total prize money$=n*x$, n is the number of participants and x is the entree fee collected from each one, $a$ is the prize money given to the top ranker, $r$ is the common ratio and $n$ should be set to $n/3$, now you decide what should be the ratio and work out prize for each of the following rankers by $ar^{n-1}$ for nth ranker

Comment: @vikram Thanks, just looking at his now

Comment: I've set up a test page but the numbers arn't looking right http://www.fantasyallpro.com/test.html
I'll be honest and i'm not sure i'm understanding the whole process.
My test script seems to pay out more than is in the prize pool! as the number of players progress.

Comment: @vikram Can i just check a few things: a is the value of (1-rn) ?
What does the 1 relate too, is it the value of S ?
I did say in my OP my maths skills are lacking!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say there are $n$ participants and each one pays $ x$ pounds as entree fee, so we have $n\times x$ pounds collection and this you wish to distribute among $\frac{n}{3}$ top participants.

One way to distribute this amount is to use Geometrical Progression.  The sum of all terms in a GP is given by $S=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$, here $a$ is the first term, $r$ is the common ration and $n$ is the number of terms.  In your case $S=n\times x$ and the number of terms $=\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor=m $ and let's say you select $r=0.75$, then $3mx=\frac{a(1-0.75^m)}{1-0.75}\Rightarrow a=\frac{0.75mx}{1-0.75^m}$.

Now, using the numbers provided by you, if $n=5000$ then $m=1666$ and $ x=4.5$, so the amount you expect to collect is $5000 \times 4.5 = 22500$ pounds, this amount you wish to distribute among $1666$ top rankers.

The first prize will be $a=\frac{0.75\times 1666 \times 4.5}{1-0.75^{1666}} \approx 5622.75$

The second prize will be $ar^{n-1}=5622.75 \times 0.75^{(2-1)} \approx4217.06$

The third prize will be $5622.75\times 0.75^{3-1} \approx 3162.79$

The fourth prize will be $5622.75\times 0.75^{4-1} \approx 2372.09$

The fifth prize will be $5622.75\times 0.75^{5-1} \approx 1779.07$

can you continue?